# Spring application run in jetty server but not in jboss

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a GWT Application that uses spring MVC, when I run this application in a jetty server it works perfectly but when I run the war in the JBoss 7.1.1 server with JDK 7, I have the problem 404 and in the log, I found this line :

```
16:08:15,231 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rci_sof/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

can anyone explain why it works in jetty and not in JBoss server and what should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: i don't use spring boot, we use jdk7 and jboss 7.1.1 versions.

Comment: More details are needed to respond: Like which URL do you use in your request? And what does your web.xml or @WebServlet annotation look like?

Comment: You can check this anwser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752124/404-error-using-spring-mvc-java-config-on-jboss

Comment: or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666513/spring-java-config-vs-jboss-7